# Text Alignment off in iMac Safari works on Laptop Safari, and Iphone Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, shopify

I'm customizing a current theme in Shopify everything looks great in Chrome, Firefox, etc. I looked on a Iphone/Ipad and it looks great in Safari.

But whenever I go to the website on my Imac (21.5 inch) the text on the homepage banner is running off the right side of the screen.

Working with Safari V8

Any help is greatly appreciated

link: http://beachriot.com/

I wish there was a easy solution (like everybody) to cross-browsing compatibility.

Comment: I tried this at multiple screen resolutions, and saw no breaks. You're probably missing a specific `@media-query` target, but again I didn't see any break. There is though, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which is the most compatible for all browsers and screen sizes. Also please show some working code next time so we can help you de-bug it.

Comment: Thanks Scoopzilla, I was looking for a @media-query error but thought that wouldn't make sense because it's not a responsive issue it's a browser issue. Like I said, it works on Safari laptop just not desktop.

Comment: I tried adding code, but it's too long. Can I e-mail you directly? Or maybe there's a efficient way to add to form?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your iMac running the same version of Safari as the laptop?

Comment: Yes, thanks. @scoopzilla

Comment: Your site is very useful and I would try to have others that have that same computer try to recreate your issue. However, it seems like a non-issue. Regardless, I would try to isolate the CSS that you think controls where your problem is occurring and post it here. Not the entire css sheet.

Comment: CSS That controls the slider: [code] [/code]